# How to include windows azure mobile feauture in c++/cx windows 8 application?

Tags: windows, azure

I am making windows 8 application using c++/cx but i am not able to get how to include azure feature in my app,every where tutorials is given in c# but nowhere i can find tutorial in c++/cx.

Answer (score 1):

As most of the samples written in managed code to access Windows Azure Mobile Services, It is trues that there are no samples available  in C++/C. However it does not mean you could not do it. Keep in mind you would need to do extra work to get it done.

As Windows Azure Mobile Services use RESTful interface so you can access them from any language as long as you can call REST api from there. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj710108.aspx) is the documentation for Windows Azure Mobile Services REST Api.

With C++/C you just need to search and find an appropriate framework to call REST api and once you have that working just call Windows Azure Mobile TEST Api to achieve your objective.

Answer (score 0):

[This blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/11/05/using-windows-azure-mobile-services-from-c-windows-store-apps.aspx) has some examples of how to perform various Azure Mobile Services tasks using C++ for Windows 8.1 Store apps.  The IDE tooling mentioned in that post is not available for Windows 8 apps.